# Función con scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Buenas estoy haciendo una función con scroll.

Cuando baja el scroll 150 muestro un banner en la parte de abajo y al subir el scroll a tope se vuelve a esconder.

```
$(function() {
  // esta parte es la que controla cuando se mueve el scroll y ejecuta una función
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    // aca se pregunta si el scroll se movio de pa bajo.
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 150) {
      // esta parte cambia el atributo "src" de la etiqueta "img"
      $('.barraTella').css("bottom","-200px");
      $('.barraTella').css("transition","1s");
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
      $('.barraTella').css("bottom","0px");
      $('.barraTella').css("transition","1s");
    }
  });
});
```

Pero también le añadí un botón para poder cerrar ese banner.

```
$( "#closeLlama" ).click(function() {
    $('#barraTella').css("bottom","-200px");
    $('#barraTella').css("transition","1s");
  });
```

El problema está en que, si lo cierro, y hago de nuevo scroll se me vuelve a mostrar.

Lo que necesito es: que hasta que no vuelva a subir del todo y vuelva a hacer esos 150 hacia abajo, no se vuelva a mostrar.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una `var` para que cuando clickes le cambie el valor a esa variable:

```
var buttonClicked= false;
```

y en el
 `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150 && buttonClicked==false)` compruebas que esa variable siga como estaba (es decir no se ha clickado aun).
Si en el evento del click le cambias la variable ya no entrara ahí

```
$( "#closeLlama" ).click(function() {
        buttonClicked=true;
      });
```

Para acabar reinicias la variable cuando el scroll vuelva arriba:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 150) {
      buttonClicked=false;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  var buttonClicked= false;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
  $("#outputScrollPosition").html("Scroll position:"+$(this).scrollTop()+"<br>Click: "+buttonClicked.toString());
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 150) {
      buttonClicked=false;
      $('.barraTella').css("bottom","-200px");
      $('.barraTella').css("transition","1s");
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150 && buttonClicked==false) {
      $('.barraTella').css("bottom","0px");
      $('.barraTella').css("transition","1s");
    }
  });
  $( "#closeLlama" ).click(function() { 
    buttonClicked=true;
    $('#barraTella').css("bottom","-200px");
    $('#barraTella').css("transition","1s");
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 800px;
}

.barraTella {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#closeLlama {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#outputScrollPosition{
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <button id="closeLlama">cerrar</button>
  <div id="barraTella" class="barraTella">
    BRUCE BANNER
  </div>
  <div id="outputScrollPosition"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wowww!!! grande @Parra. Me sirvio al 100% muchas gracias!